# unable to parse csv file with CHCSV parser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, csv

I am using `CHSV` parser to parse `csv` file , but am getting nothing in console, The below code am using to parse the csv. I imported CHSV header file and mentioned `CHCSVParserDelegate` even I checked the csv file name too

```
 CHCSVParser *parser=[[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gapunditprogeorgiastatehouse.csv"] delimiter:','];
  parser.delegate=self;
  [parser parse];

-(void) parserDidBeginDocument:(CHCSVParser *)parser
{
  currentRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(CHCSVParser *)parser
{
  for(int i=0;i<[currentRow count];i++)
  {
    NSLog(@"%@          %@          %@",[[currentRow objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"]],[[currentRow objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]],[[currentRow objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"]]);
  }
}

- (void) parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"Parser failed with error: %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}

-(void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didBeginLine:(NSUInteger)recordNumber
{
  dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}

-(void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didReadField:(NSString *)field atIndex:(NSInteger)fieldIndex
{
  [dict setObject:field forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fieldIndex]];
}

- (void) parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didEndLine:(NSUInteger)lineNumber
{
  [currentRow addObject:dict];
  dict=nil;
}
```

Comment: what the error  u faced.....

Comment: i got nothing with chsv parser

Comment: Have you verified that the path is correct and doesn't return nil?

Comment: what the result u get in [currentRow addObject:dict];

Comment: ya i've verified the path @boyfarrell,

Answer (score 1):

My csv file is some thing like this

```
India;26;F;New Delhi;20000;NO;0;2009
France;30;M;New York;20000;NO;1;2009
Germany;24;F;New York;20000;NO;0;2009
Mexico;28;M;New Delhi;20000;NO;1;2009
```

To read this csv file i used this method:

```
NSMutableArray *arrTitle=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *fileDataString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *linesArray=[fileDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

 [linesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
  {
     NSArray *columnArray=[obj componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
     [arrTitle addObject:[columnArray objectAtIndex:0]];

 }];


NSLog(@"%@",arrTitle);
```

Here path is your csv file path.

Output is:

```
(
 India,
 France,
 Germany,
 Mexico
)
```

Comment: instead of semicolon i used comma, but its working only for first column @nandu

Comment: @Coolcracker -- r u checked this line [arrTitle addObject:[columnArray objectAtIndex:0]]; he get only **0th** index

Comment: hey anbu i got a seviour bug with your code to parse columns @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: i checked the columnarray count it is just only 1 :( i have 26 columns in csv